# FileZilla Connection timed out, Error Connecting to Server

Tags: ftp-client, filezilla, request-timed-out

I am having an issue with FileZilla, when I try access my FTP account, I get this:

```
Status: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xx (Ip adds:port)
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Could not connect to server
Status: Waiting to retry...
Status: Connecting to (Ip adds:port)
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

This was **working fine till yesterday**. It **works on another pc**, but its **not working** onn **my pc** now. I tried disabling Windows Firewall (as I am using Windows 8 OS).  Also I completely reinstalled FileZilla, still that didn't do it. Is there anything more I can try?

Comment: Try if you can `ping` the host.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was connected to the Internet from another Laptop, with sharing the internet connection. So there was the problem, it had restricted to access the ports. When I connected directly to the Internet the problem was solved.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. Turned out I was using an incorrect protocol to login to the ftp server. The ftp server was ssh secured. Selecting SFTP option instead of FTP worked for me.

https://vincent254.wordpress.com/2015/03/16/what-to-do-incase-you-get-this-filezilla-connection-error/

Comment: Same issue here, except the QuickConnect bar does not have an FTP/SFTP option.  Go into File->Site Manager->New Site and the option is found there.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to write the host in this format

> ftp.example.com

This works if you are having the following error as well

> ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server

Answer (score -1):

Change Your Internet Connection then connect FileZilla

thanks